# Filter rows in Google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet. There is a colour column. Every row has a colour, Red, Yellow, Green etc. I want to be able to filter out say all rows that are Red, all rows that are yellow, all rows that any colour except Green, Green rows only etc.

Any tips on how to do this? I want to do this so the user viewing the spreadsheet can do it dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Literally, you **can't** (see [this topic on Google Group](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/docs-community/Pr9ZCCPnkAw)).

You'd better use the Google Conditional Formating system:

- Highlight a new column
- Click the tool to select a color
- Choose to "`change with rules`"
- Create a match, e.g. cell contains "x" equals red
- Then when you sort that column you'll get sorting by color.

Comment: Better yet, instead of "x" use values of "red", "yellow", and "green" (etc.).  Use conditional formatting to colorize the cells properly, plus your filter options will be easy to understand!